# How to check if SQLAlwaysON is existing in server using powershell without a SQL DBA Admin access?

Tags: sql, database, powershell

I want to check if `SQLAlwaysON` exists in server.

I already know that typing and getting the powershell commands `Enable-SQLServerAlwaysON` and `Disabled-SQLServerAlwaysON` are a great hint for that.
But it won't work if there's no `SQLAlwaysON` tool and I don't want to Enable or Disable it.

Appreciate if someone can provide a simple but very good idea to check if `SQLAlwaysON` exists using powershell command. Thanks a lot!

[SQLAlwaysON check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/enable-and-disable-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#PScmd2Procedure)

**UPDATE:**

I posted my solution below because the account that I use in checking is not a `SQL DB Admin account` and there's no way I could get an access inside the database server (security related).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this can work for you:

```
if ( ( Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('IsHadrEnabled') AS IsHadrEnabled" -ServerInstance "localhost" ).IsHadrEnabled ) {
    Write-Host "HADR is enabled."
}
else {
    Write-Host "HADR is NOT enabled."
}
```

References:

[Invoke-Sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd)

[SERVERPROPERTY (Transact-SQL) -> IsHadrEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql)

> IsHadrEnabled
>
> Applies to: SQL Server 2012 (11.x) and later.
>
> Always On availability groups is enabled on this server instance.
>
> 0 = The Always On availability groups feature is disabled.
>
> 1 = The Always On availability groups feature is enabled.
>
> NULL = Input is not valid, an error, or not applicable.
>
> Base data type: int
>
> For availability replicas to be created and run on an instance of SQL
>   Server, Always On availability groups must be enabled on the server
>   instance. For more information, see Enable and Disable AlwaysOn
>   Availability Groups (SQL Server).
>
> Note: The IsHadrEnabled property pertains only to Always On
>   availability groups. Other high availability or disaster recovery
>   features, such as database mirroring or log shipping, are unaffected
>   by this server property.

Comment: I'll check on that! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but someone might find it useful, no SQL permissions required:

```
if (Get-ClusterResource -Cluster "CLUSTER ADDRESS" | `
    Where-Object { $_.ResourceType -eq "SQL Server Availability Group" }) {
  "SQL Server AlwaysOn Availability Group exists on this cluster"
} else {
  "NOPE"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I don't have a `SQL Admin account` so I cannot query inside the database. I only have a `Local Server Admin account` and cannot have any SQL Admin account due to security reasons.

I used the following to check if `FailoverClusters` module exists in server. Not encouraging to use as a checking but this module is a prerequisite to enable `SQLAlwaysON`.

It is still not enough to tell that `SQLAlwaysON` is existing in server. I suggest to double check too whenever you have a SQL Admin account using `@BiNZGi`'s answer. `HADR` is critical component for AG.

`PS script`

`if (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name FailoverClusters) {`

`Write-Host "SQLServerAlwaysON may exists."`

`}`

Answer (score 0):

You can query regdb

```
$servername = ''
$hadrcheck = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servername -ScriptBlock {(Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\*\MSSQLServer\HADR').hadr_enabled}
if($hadrcheck = 1){write-host "it is enabled"}
else{write-host "it is NOT enabled"}
```